# How to set weights for Convolution2D?

Tags: keras

I would like to set the weights of a `Convolution2D` layer:

```py
conv = Convolution2D(conv_out_size, window_size, embedding_size,
                     border_mode='same',
                     activation='relu',
                     weights=weights,
                     name='conv_{:d}'.format(i))(in_x)
```

but I am not sure what's expected here. I've tried several thing but most of the time I get

```
ValueError: You called `set_weights(weights)` on layer "conv_0" with a  weight list of length 1, but the layer was expecting 2 weights.
```

Not sure what this exactly means.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You should pass a numpy array to your convolutional layer through the set_weights method.

Remember that the weights of a convolutional layer are not only the weights of each individual filter, but also the **bias**. So if you want to set your weights you need to add an extra dimension.

For example, if you want to set a 1x3x3 filter with all weights zero except for the central element, you should make it:

```
w = np.asarray([ 
    [[[
    [0,0,0],
    [0,2,0],
    [0,0,0]
    ]]]
    ])
```

And then set it.

For a code you could run:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import print_function
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(1234)
from keras.layers import Input
from keras.layers.convolutional import Convolution2D
from keras.models import Model
print("Building Model...")
inp = Input(shape=(1,None,None))
output   = Convolution2D(1, 3, 3, border_mode='same', init='normal',bias=False)(inp)
model_network = Model(input=inp, output=output)
print("Weights before change:")
print (model_network.layers[1].get_weights())
w = np.asarray([ 
    [[[
    [0,0,0],
    [0,2,0],
    [0,0,0]
    ]]]
    ])
input_mat = np.asarray([ 
    [[
    [1.,2.,3.],
    [4.,5.,6.],
    [7.,8.,9.]
    ]]
    ])
model_network.layers[1].set_weights(w)
print("Weights after change:")
print(model_network.layers[1].get_weights())
print("Input:")
print(input_mat)
print("Output:")
print(model_network.predict(input_mat))
```

Try changing the central element in the convolutional fillter (2 in the example).

What the code does:

At first build a model.

```
inp = Input(shape=(1,None,None))
output   = Convolution2D(1, 3, 3, border_mode='same', init='normal',bias=False)(inp)
model_network = Model(input=inp, output=output)
```

Print your original weights (initialized with normal distribution, init='normal' )

```
print (model_network.layers[1].get_weights())
```

Create your desired weight tensor w and some input input_mat

```
w = np.asarray([ 
    [[[
    [0,0,0],
    [0,2,0],
    [0,0,0]
    ]]]
    ])
input_mat = np.asarray([ 
    [[
    [1.,2.,3.],
    [4.,5.,6.],
    [7.,8.,9.]
    ]]
    ])
```

set your weights and print them

```
model_network.layers[1].set_weights(w)
print("Weights after change:")
print(model_network.layers[1].get_weights())
```

Finally, use it to generate output with predict (predict automatically compiles your model)

```
print(model_network.predict(input_mat))
```

Example Output:

```
Using Theano backend.
Building Model...
Weights before change:
[array([[[[ 0.02357176, -0.05954878,  0.07163535],
         [-0.01563259, -0.03602944,  0.04435815],
         [ 0.04297942, -0.03182618,  0.00078482]]]], dtype=float32)]
Weights after change:
[array([[[[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
         [ 0.,  2.,  0.],
         [ 0.,  0.,  0.]]]], dtype=float32)]
Input:
[[[[ 1.  2.  3.]
   [ 4.  5.  6.]
   [ 7.  8.  9.]]]]
Output:
[[[[  2.   4.   6.]
   [  8.  10.  12.]
   [ 14.  16.  18.]]]]
```

Comment: Oh, thanks! That wasn't clear to me. The docs didn't specify the exact requirements for the shape of the weights. Thank you for your examples!