# how to initialize layers by numpy array in keras

Tags: initialization, keras, convolution

I want to convert a pre-trained caffe model to keras, then i need to initialize the layers , layer by layer. 
I saved the weights and biases in a mat file and I loaded them to python workspace. 
I know "weights" parameter get the numpy array but not how?
Thanks

Comment: for convolutional layers check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42211619/how-to-set-weights-for-convolution2d/42212349#42212349

Comment: @maz , it was useful

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get more information about how to set the weight of a model in the [Keras Layers Documentation](https://keras.io/layers/about-keras-layers/). Basically you use :

> `layer.set_weights(weights)`: sets the weights of the layer from a list of Numpy arrays (with the same shapes as the output of `get_weights`).

Or you can directly initialize them when you create the layer. Every layer has a parameter `weights` that you can set with a numpy array. Read [each layer's documentation](https://keras.io/layers/core/) to feed the right weights format. For example, `Dense()` layers accept this format for the parameter `weights` :

> List of Numpy arrays to set as initial weights. The list should have 2 elements, of shape (input_dim, output_dim) and (output_dim,) for weights and biases respectively. [source](https://keras.io/layers/core/#dense)

Comment: Is there a way to use a keras initializer to construct a numpy array? E.g. `glorot_uniform()(shape) -> ndarray([...])`

Comment: @BallpointBen did you find a solution to this? Seems to be an issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56190405/keras-kernel-initialization-with-numpy-array-unable-to-use-load-model