# Can Convolution2D work on rectangular images?

Tags: python, image, keras, convolution

Let's say I have a 360px by 240px image. Instead of cropping my (already small) image to 240x240, can I create a convolutional neural network that operates on the full rectangle? Specifically using the `Convolution2D` layer.

I ask because every paper I've read doing CNNs seems to have square input sizes, so I wonder if what I propose will be OK, and if so, what disadvantages I may run into. Are all the settings (like `border_mode='same'`) going to work the same?

Comment: Have you read the documentation? https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/#convolution2d

Comment: This doesn't explicitly address my question, but it doesn't seem to suggest that there would be any problems either.

Comment: I thought the `input_shape` parameter would explicitly answer your question. My apologies if it did not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No issues with a rectangle image... Everything will work properly as for square images.

Comment: Cool, I'll trust this reassurance and try it out on my next project. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

But why don't you give it a try

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import print_function
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(1234)
from keras.layers import Input
from keras.layers.convolutional import Convolution2D
from keras.models import Model

print("Building Model...")
inp = Input(shape=(1,None,None))
output   = Convolution2D(1, 3, 3, border_mode='same', init='normal',bias=False)(inp)
model_network = Model(input=inp, output=output)
w = np.asarray([ 
    [[[
    [0,0,0],
    [0,2,0],
    [0,0,0]
    ]]]
    ])
input_mat = np.asarray([ 
    [[
    [1.,2.,3.,10.],
    [4.,5.,6.,11.],
    [7.,8.,9.,12.]
    ]]
    ])
model_network.layers[1].set_weights(w)
print("Weights after change:")
print(model_network.layers[1].get_weights())
print("Input:")
print(input_mat)
print("Output:")
print(model_network.predict(input_mat))
```

Build a sample model

```
inp = Input(shape=(1,None,None))
output   = Convolution2D(1, 3, 3, border_mode='same', init='normal',bias=False)(inp)
model_network = Model(input=inp, output=output)
```

Give it some weights and set them so you could predit the output, say:

```
w = np.asarray([ 
    [[[
    [0,0,0],
    [0,2,0],
    [0,0,0]
    ]]]
    ])
model_network.layers[1].set_weights(w)
```

So that the convolution would simply double your input.

Give it your rectangular image:

```
input_mat = np.asarray([ 
    [[
    [1.,2.,3.,10.],
    [4.,5.,6.,11.],
    [7.,8.,9.,12.]
    ]]
    ])
```

And check the output to see if it works

```
print("Output:")
print(model_network.predict(input_mat))
```

Sample output:

```
Using Theano backend.
Building Model...
Weights after change:
[array([[[[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
         [ 0.,  2.,  0.],
         [ 0.,  0.,  0.]]]], dtype=float32)]
Input:
[[[[  1.   2.   3.  10.]
   [  4.   5.   6.  11.]
   [  7.   8.   9.  12.]]]]
Output:
[[[[  2.   4.   6.  20.]
   [  8.  10.  12.  22.]
   [ 14.  16.  18.  24.]]]]
```

original [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42211619/how-to-set-weights-for-convolution2d/42212349#42212349) with some changes