# keras: set_weights() doesn't change values

Tags: keras, keras-layer

Using accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42211619/how-to-set-weights-for-convolution2d),I'm trying to change layer's weights with set_weights() method, but it seems don't work...
here the code I used

```python
from keras.layers import Input
from keras.layers.convolutional import Convolution2D
from keras.models import Model
import numpy as np
print("Building Model...")
inp = Input(shape=(20,20,1))
output   = Convolution2D(1, (3,3), padding='same',bias=False)(inp)
model_network=Model(inp, output)


print("Weights before change:")
print (model_network.layers[1].get_weights())
w = np.asarray([ 
    [[[
    [2,2,2],
    [2,2,2],
    [2,2,2]
    ]]]
    ])

w=np.reshape(w,np.shape(model_network.layers[1].get_weights()))
#print("W:",w)

model_network.layers[1].set_weights(w)
print("Weights after change:")
print(model_network.layers[1].get_weights())
```

but my weights remain the same; (output in comments)

Comment: I get as output:
    
    Building Model...

    Weights before change:
    [array([[[[0.]],   
            [[0.]],    
            [[0.]]],
        
           [[[0.]],    
            [[0.]],    
            [[0.]]],
       
           [[[0.]],   
            [[0.]],   
            [[0.]]]], dtype=float32)]
    Weights after change:
    [array([[[[0.]],
    
            [[0.]],
            [[0.]]],
       
           [[[0.]],   
            [[0.]],  
            [[0.]]],
    
    
           [[[0.]],
            [[0.]],
            [[0.]]]], dtype=float32)]

Comment: What is your keras version?

Comment: version is 2.1.5